# How to Get Data from Multiple Cells and Combine into a Comment in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript, google-sheets-custom-function

I have a spreadsheet of orders (rows) that has room for 70 products (columns). I would like for a script to find every cell that has a value (0's are blank) and then write that value (this is the qty of cases) to a note/comment along with the heading information that displays what product this is for.

For example, if an order has 5 cases of Pink and 7 cases of Blue, I would like this note to read

Pink - 5
Blue - 7

Comment: If you could share a sample spreadsheet and explain where you would like the note to be written. It would be easier to figure out how to help you.